# Dividing listbox into several columns with headers

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to divide a listbox into several columns, so that I add an item by calling `Listbox.items.add(item);` and it will display with different properties in different columns. Here is my code so far:

```
 <ListBox Name="listbox1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:ScheduledEvent">
                <Grid Margin="0 5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>                            
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="3 0 3 0" FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding WorldRank}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Country}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding GraduationYear}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Use a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a ListBox.

Comment: use a GridView instead of a ListBox